# How to pass variables as params into Flow on website?

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, digital-experience

I have a website where I want to use my flow and based on user behaviour insert hidden variables into the flow that the user is not supposed to insert himself.

How do I pass params into the flow and how do I use them in the flow builder? I tried this.

html:

```
<lightning-flow flow-api-name="TestLWCFLOW" flow-params={inputVariables}></lightning-flow>
```

js:

```
get inputVariables() {
        return [
            {
                name: 'test',
                type: 'String',
                value: '99'
            }
        ];
    }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to simply refer to the variable as `{recordId}`?

Comment: @PhilW yes, it does not work

Comment: Did you create the `recordId` variable as "is input" in your flow?

Comment: @PhilW Do you mean "Available for input"? I tried that and still dont work

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. This approach does work - I suggest you haven't configured something right in your flow. Please [edit] your question to include detail of the way you have defined the variable in your flow (a screenshot of the variable definition will do).

Comment: @PhilW I added some screenshots now

Comment: That variable is called "test". You need to use the name "test" in your inputVariables definition...

Comment: You don't use "inputVariables. *name*" to access the variable; just define the "*name*" as a variable that is "available for input" and use that in the flow.

Comment: @PhilW I edited the question again to what you said. Now as you see the variable is just blank. Is there something wrong with the way I pass params in the HTML?

Comment: You need to use `<lightning-flow flow-api-name="TestLWCFLOW" flow-input-variables={inputVariables}></lightning-flow>`; you have misnamed the attributes on your flow invocation.

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!!!!! THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML template invocation of the `lightning-flow` isn't quite right. Change it to:

```
<lightning-flow flow-api-name="TestLWCFLOW" flow-input-variables={inputVariables}></lightning-flow>
```